# Limit with not operator is not working correctly MySql

Tags: mysql, limit

I am using a query as below with not operator in where and limit. I am not able get correct sequencing of data (Without limit clause it is different and with limit ordering of data is something different).

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM `table` WHERE (1 AND id_type!=1) ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 2


Table Structure with sample data:
id      id_type
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        3
5        3
6        3
```

Any Suggestions ?

```
Expected Output : 

6
5

But When I remove the limit ordering is not same : 

5
6
4
3
2
```

Note: This is just an sample data structure. Original table is contains much fields and different columns.

Comment: What output do you want ?

Comment: Аutor want to say, that order is wrong. I can not belive that limit cause bad order.

Comment: It is causing , I check with having clause instead of where it worked fine.

Comment: You probably removed the `order by` as well as the `limit`.

Comment: Why () before distinct? try without ().

Comment: Try: select * from (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM `table` WHERE (1 AND id_type!=1) limit 2 ) ORDER BY id desc

Comment: may be better obtain two values in one row?  select max(a.id) id1, max( case when  b.id <> max(a.id) from `table` b ) id2 from `table` a?

Comment: What's the point of `WHERE (1 AND` why not simply `WHERE id_type!=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is no problem at all. See this.

```
MariaDB [fbb]> SELECT * FROM `test`;
+----+---------+
| id | id_type |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |
|  3 |       2 |
|  4 |       3 |
|  5 |       3 |
|  6 |       3 |
+----+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [fbb]> SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM `test` WHERE (1 AND id_type!=1) ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 2;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  6 |
|  5 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [fbb]>
```

Comment: Maybe I was not able to explain the scenario with existing schema. Anyways, Thanks for your help.